# getJSON Facebook call not working in IE

Tags: jquery, facebook, internet-explorer, getjson

So I'm trying to  Pull a Facebook feed with works in all browsers but not IE.

It pulls the feed and outputs it to a   in the main page.

Any suggestions?

```
      $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/"+user+"/feed&limit="+limit+"?"+token+"", function(data) {
          for(emp in data.data) {
              console.log(data.data[emp]);
           //  If adding CSS style the DIVS below can change the P tags
              var newRow = "<div class=\"FB-post\">"+
              // note using the fuzzyFacebookTime to convert JSON time tag to readable time.
                              "<p><a href='https://www.facebook.com/pages/123456789/123456789' target='_blank'><img src='/123456789/images/facebook_logo_20x20.jpg' style='padding-right:10px;' /></a><small><i>Posted "+fuzzyFacebookTime(data.data[emp].updated_time.replace(/-/g,'/'))+"</i></small></p>"+
                              "<p>"+data.data[emp].message+"</p>"+
                              "<p class=\"FB-more-link\"><a href='https://www.facebook.com/pages/123456789/123456789' target='_blank'>click here to read more</a></p>"+
                           "</div>";
              $("#EmpNewTable").prepend(newRow);
          } 
      });

  });
```

});

Comment: What version of IE? What error message(s) are you getting, if any? Are you sure it's not just your console.log killing it? Some browsers don't like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console` is not defined in IE remove the line

```
 console.log(data.data[emp]);
```

and you are good to go, or you can check before logging

```
if (typeof console != "undefined") {
     console.log(data.data[emp]);
}
```

Comment: I removed the console.log(data.data[emp); line but still no resolve. I had thought that IE might have a odd way of rendering the script.[link](http://danetaylor.com/bob/index.html)

Comment: So I added some alert within the script and it stops loading the first `$.get("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=119426091522594&client_secret=f821e45fbbe5e918946178e0cdf06eac&grant_type=client_credentials&format=json", function(data) {
              var token = data;
`